# After installing SASS on CentOS, the command "sass" cannot be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unix, sass, centos, rubygems

I've installed SASS successfully, and right after, when I run the command "sass", it doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong?

```
[dane@dev-vpc-01 home]$ sudo gem install sass --no-user-install
Successfully installed sass-3.5.5
Parsing documentation for sass-3.5.5
Done installing documentation for sass after 14 seconds
1 gem installed
[dane@dev-vpc-01 home]$ sass
bash: sass: command not found
[dane@dev-vpc-01 home]$ which sass
/usr/bin/which: no sass in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin)
```

Comment: Try `echo $PATH` and see if your GEM_HOME directory is included.

Comment: Have you tried with `sass --help`

Comment: @SebastiánMeza `sass --help` is not going to help if sass itself cannot be found.